# redis session not working on server

Tags: node.js, express, redis

I am using redis for session in my node.js express app. It works fine on my dev box, but on production, it seems redis sessions are not being saved.

I'm not seeing any kind of error, other than I cannot login.

Redis is running w/ same configuration. But when I run `redis-cli` and type '`select 1`' (the db) and `KEYS '*'` I get nothing.

```
  var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(express);

  app.use(express.session({
    store: new RedisStore({
      host: cfg.redis.host,
      db: cfg.redis.db
    }),
    secret: 'sauce'
  }));
```

cfg.redis.host is localhost
and cfg.redis.db is 1

This is the error I get when I run `redis-cli monitor`

```
Error: Protocol error, got "s" as reply type byte
```

Comment: Show some example code (preferably a minimal test case).

Comment: Is your "cfg" different in dev/pros env?

Comment: Can you tell the version of redis server and node, express, connect-redis ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few suggestions. Are you sure Redis uses the same port and password in production? If you're using SSL with a service like Heroku, you need to set proxy: true to have Express treat cookies that arrive after after earlier SSL termination.

```
   .use(express.session({
        store: new RedisStore({
            port: config.redisPort,
            host: config.redisHost,
            db: config.redisDatabase,
            pass: config.redisPassword}),
        secret: 'sauce',
        proxy: true,
        cookie: { secure: true }
    }))
```

I require the following config.js file to pass on Redis config values:

```
var url = require('url')
var config = {};
var redisUrl;

if (typeof(process.env.REDISTOGO_URL) != 'undefined') {
    redisUrl = url.parse(process.env.REDISTOGO_URL);
}
else redisUrl = url.parse('redis://:@127.0.0.1:6379/0');

config.redisProtocol = redisUrl.protocol.substr(0, redisUrl.protocol.length - 1); // Remove trailing ':'
config.redisUsername = redisUrl.auth.split(':')[0];
config.redisPassword = redisUrl.auth.split(':')[1];
config.redisHost = redisUrl.hostname;
config.redisPort = redisUrl.port;
config.redisDatabase = redisUrl.path.substring(1);

console.log('Using Redis store ' + config.redisDatabase)

module.exports = config;
```